# Java concurrency/networking approach

Tags: java, networking, concurrency

I am developing a stand-alone java application which gathers data from around 1000 measuring devices over the network and persists the data to a database.
The data gathering can take a couple of minutes per device due to slow device output and/or network speed. The data gathering must take place in a certain time window, so i need to work in parallel.

My approach would be to create one thread per measuring device, put the data in a queue and have one or more other threads at the other end of the queue transform and persist the data.

Is this a viable approach? Will a modern machine be able to handle that many threads and network connections? How scalable is this, at what point would i need to work on several machines?

I would also be grateful if you could give me pointers with regard to the concurreny classes you would recommend (i.e. what kind of queue, ThreadPoolExecutor etc - i havent used java.util.concurrent yet, book is in the mail).

Are there any better approaches?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the answers so far, here is more information requested by some of you.

The data i receive from the devices is in the form of files smaller than 1kb. It is possible that i get something like 25.000 files during one transfer, although usually its far less.

The data transformation is nothing cpu-intensive, basically parsing the file and converting it to java data types (the file contains c-data-types like unsigned char and unix timestamps), plus a CRC calculation. I create an object containing the content of one file which i persist to the datbase using JPA (i guess i could use plain JDBC as well for this case). There is no order in the measurements-files, since they contain the device s/n and a timestamp.

At a later point in time i will have to add some kind of alert when certain criteria are met, but again this shouldn't be cpu-intensive.

From the answers so far i gather the network connections and number of threads shouldn't be a problem.

The only thing i'm left wondering is about the approach with the queue. An alternative would be to let the data-gathering threads also call the DAO method to persist the file. I guess i have to make the DAOs thread-safe anyway, but i think a few threads could do the job as well, since the bulk of the time will be spent transferring network-data.

Also i will look into asynchronous I/O and some frameworks that provide it.

Thanks again, i will choose an answer a little bit later, maybe i will get some more input :)

Comment: "put the data in a queue" - what kind of data are you going to put in that queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default settings you'll end up using around 1Gb of memory for the threads' stacks, given you are running on 64-bit Linux, Oracle jdk (default threadstacksize is 1Mb on such a platform). I think for OpenJDK it is the same. Not counting buffers allocated by the os . . .

If this is too much for your requirements, you may want to have a look at http://netty.io. This framework uses java nio under the hood (can be configured to use bio, btw). This way you would just require a handful of threads for doing the actual io (performing read/write ops on for a given tcp connection). Your business logic (update db, calculate some measurements) should then be offloaded into a separate threadpool. Netty also includes support for this.

If you want to use 1 thread per connection (per measuring device?), then there is probably no benefit from having yet another bunch of threads doing the actual business work. I assume one thread per device, because you said that the device can be slow and/or the network can be slow. Both bottlenecks (network and device) won't be eliminated if you're  using multiple threads (one can expect the opposite).

Concurrency classes in general: java.util.concurrent.* yep, both thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

For a modern OS and hardware, handling 1000+change threads and network connection shouldn't be a problem. The real question is how much data you're gathering, and how complex the transformations are - that's probably going to determine how much one machine can handle.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should consider Asynchronous IO for gathering the data from the devices. Once you have read something from a socket, post this to a queue (concurrent or otherwise), and have a pool of threads reading items off of this queue.

The only complication is maintaining data in natural order for device, maybe you can have a queue per device, and the post some sort of token to the queue that the thread pool is connected to indicating which device is ready for processing. A thread will then process the queue for the device and do the necessary work, if it needs more data, it doesn't have to consume from the device queue, it can leave it there till all the data has arrived.